# How to create table and insert data in sqlite +juce

Tags: sqlite, juce

can you please tell me how to create data base in sqlite .can you please tell me how to create table and insert data in sqlite +c++.I don't get much help in internet .Can you please give some example so that I am able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it:

```
char *sql;
int rc = 0;

File *fptr_db = new File(DBPath);

if(fptr_db->existsAsFile())
{

} else {
    sqlite3_initialize( );
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2( DBPath.toRawUTF8(), &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close( pDb );
        exit( -1 );
    }
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, GroupId integer NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, Password VARCHAR(200) COLLATE NOCASE, Address VARCHAR(200) COLLATE NOCASE, PostalCode VARCHAR(20), Vat VARCHAR(30), BI INT, LastSale DATE, Limits DECIMAL(12,6), Commission DECIMAL(12,6), BirthDate DATE, Phone VARCHAR(20), MobilePhone VARCHAR(20), Email VARCHAR(200) COLLATE NOCASE, Obs VARCHAR, DefaultSerieId integer NOT NULL ); ";
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( pDb, sql, -1, &query, NULL );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK) exit( -1 );
    rc = sqlite3_step( query );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_DONE ) exit ( -1 );

    sql = "INSERT INTO [Users] ([Id], [GroupId], [Name], [Password], [DefaultSerieId]) VALUES (1, 0, 'Paulo', '1234', 0)";
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( pDb, sql, -1, &query, NULL );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK) exit( -1 );
    rc = sqlite3_step( query );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_DONE ) exit ( -1 );

    sql = "INSERT INTO [Users] ([Id], [GroupId], [Name], [Password], [DefaultSerieId]) VALUES (2, 0, 'Antonio', '', 0)";
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, sql, -1, &query, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) exit(-1);
    rc = sqlite3_step(query);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) exit(-1);

    sqlite3_finalize( query );

    sqlite3_close( pDb );
    sqlite3_shutdown( );
}
```

Works well, DBPath is a string that contains the path for the database and finalized with the name.
Example:
String DBPath = "C:\database.db";

Paulo